# Backslashes in Windows environment variables break gcc include process

Tags: windows, gcc, path, environment-variables, backslash

I'm compiling a C project using Eclipse Luna on Windows 7 64 bit

I'm using a `Makefile.in` to include external headers in the project like this:

```
CPPFLAGS += -I $(USERPROFILE)/git/path/to/include/folder
```

The problem is that `$(USERPROFILE)` expands to `C:\Users\myUser` with **backslashes** instead of forward slashes. If I hardcode the path using forward slashes, the code compiles. Otherwise I get a "file not found" when I include the headers.

I need to path to be relative so that every person in the company can use it. What could be a quick and clean workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
C:/Users/$(USERNAME)
```

is a quick solution but not as "clean" as I'd like it to be